# Transforming pyodbc connection to sqlalchemy syntax

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a connection working with pyodbc:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={};SERVER={};UID={};PWD={}".format(self.DRIVER,self.HOST,self.USER,self.PASS),autocommit=True)
```

now I want to use sqlalchemy and I trying the bellow code:

```
c="DRIVER={};SERVER={};UID={};PWD={}".format(self.DRIVER,self.HOST,self.USER,self.PASS)
quoted = quote_plus(c)
new_con = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)
self.engine = create_engine(new_con)
```

but i missing something

Can you help me and explain me please?

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQLAlchemy URL object and let it do the quoting for you:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

c = (
    "Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    "Server=192.168.0.199;"
    # …
)

conn_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    query={"odbc_connect": c}
)
engine = create_engine(conn_url)
```